# How do I PHP echo exactly what is stored in a MySQL field?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I feel like there is probably a very simple answer for this, but I've spent about 20 minutes searching and can't find anything.

Basically, I am using PHP to query a table and output the results as a list, using the primary key column (COL_1) of the table to create a link for each record that will bring the user to a detail page for that record.  It works fine when the data in COL_1 is a straight-forward string such as "TEST".  The edit link will then be `detail.php?COL_1=TEST`  The detail page works by querying the database using the data passed by the link.  So in this case it would do a select on the table where COL_1 = 'TEST' and return the correct record.

However, when new line characters are stored in COL_1 things get a bit complicated.  For instance, if 'TEST\r\nTEST' is stored in COL_1, when the original query of the entire table is done, $row['COL_1'] for that line will give me 'TESTTEST', which gets passed to the detail page as `detail.php?COL_1=TESTTEST`, the detail page does a select on the table where COL_1 = 'TESTTEST', and it returns nothing.

However, if I manually link to detail.php?COL_1=TEST\r\nTEST the detail page will query on 'TEST\r\nTEST' and return the correct record.

So basically what I need is a way to do a query and have $row['COL_1'] return 'TEST\r\nTEST' instead of 'TESTTEST'.  Does this make sense?  How would I go about doing this?

As for why the table is set up like this, don't ask me.  I didn't design it.  I'd never design keys that can include line breaks like this.  But I do have to interact with this table.  Bah.

Comment: Why is your primary key field a text field with seemingly arbitrary text on it? That's a serious red flag without a really good reason. Either way, just urlencode when making the link.

Comment: "As for why the table is set up like this, don't ask me. I didn't design it."  Believe me, I ask "why" about the way things were designed here ALL THE TIME.

Comment: @PaoloBergantino Is correct about `urlencode`. You don't need to use `urldecode`, PHP will do that automatically for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encode values that are passed in the URL:

```
echo urlencode("TEST\r\nTEST");
```

However, why would `TEST\r\nTEST` be a primary key?  That's crazy.  Maybe you need to rethink how you are doing things.  Primary keys as integers work nicely.

Comment: Yep that works!  Or rather, urlencode($row['COL_1']) works, but same thing.  I figured it would just be a single function but I couldn't find it.  Thanks!

Comment: Great.  Can you not add a new `int` column for the key?

Comment: Well... changes like that have to go through my boss, and he doesn't like me messing with established tables much.  Even if they are set up in a totally dumb way.